# Invoke callback into VB6 from native C DLL

Tags: c, vb6, callback

I am trying to get a native C function to invoke a callback in a VB6 application.  In VB, the code looks like this:

```
Private Declare Sub StartUp Lib "library.dll" (ByVal cbAddress As Long)

Public Sub MySub
    Call StartUp(AddressOf MyCallback)
End Sub

Public Sub MyCallback(ByVal str As String)
' Use str in UI
End Sub
```

When I run this from the VB6 IDE everything works great: the callback is invoked and I can use the `str` parameter no problem.  However, when I compile the VB6 application into an exe, the application will crash when the callback is invoked.  From what I can tell in my Googling it seems this is a threading issue of some sort.  Some people suggest using the Win32 `SendMessage` to avoid this threading issue somehow.  I can't quite figure out how to do this.  Would I call `SendMessage` in my callback?  How would I receive this message on the main thread?  Also, how would I pass my string into SendMessage?

Edit: I just found this:
[Vb6 application works in the IDE but the executable crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239317/vb6-application-works-in-the-ide-but-the-executable-crashes)

However, my initial questions still remain.

Edit2: I should have included in the C code as well.  This is how the callback is defined and called:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *FUNCPTR)(BSTR);
int wslen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, cstr, strlen(cstr), 0, 0);
BSTR bstr = SysAllocStringLen(0, wslen);
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, cstr, strlen(cstr), bstr, wslen);
((FUNCPTR) _cbAddress)(bstr);
SysFreeString(bstr);
```

Again, this works fine when invoked from the IDE...

Comment: You probably declared the function pointer wrong in your C code.  We can't see it.  Lots of hits when you google "callback into vb6".

Comment: @HansPassant - I just updated the question to include the C code.  And you're right, there are a lot of results from that Google query but I'm still not able to solve my problem.

Comment: That's not a BSTR.  Using SysAllocString + SysFreeString is not optional.

Comment: OK, I updated the question again.  Just wanted to reiterate that this works fine when run from the IDE so I don't believe this is an issue with the way the data marshaled.  Rather, it seems to the difference in threading models between a compiled exe and the way the application is run from the IDE.

Comment: @JasonA You haven't explained what this "crash" is, and where in the code it occurs. Can you isolate exactly what happens? For instance, is this an "Access Violation"? You also haven't said whether you have any multithreading in your C library.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw - Yes, this is an access violation crash.  The C library is multithreaded and the callback is invoked on a separate thread.  I believe I need to somehow get my callback to run on the main VB thread, but I can't quite figure out how.  The question I linked to in my first edit seems to be the closest I can come to regarding a solution but it doesn't explain enough of the details for me to understand what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the ideal thing would be for you to ensure that the callback always occurs on the VB application's main thread. Failing this, you are forced to use `SendMessage()` to a window in your application to take advantage of Window's own marshalling ability between Windows.

Ages ago that I wrote a VB app which took a callback from a DLL which was used to integrate with a remote control. But the DLL used another thread to integrate with the hardware. In my callback, I used `SendMessage()` with `WM_COPYDATA` to marshall the data to the main VB thread, which was picked up by subclassing code.

Of course, since you are writing the C DLL and you are simply passing back ASCII text, you can skip a few stages and not have to write a callback procedure or have subclassing code. Simply write text directly to a `TextBox` with the [SetWindowText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API call. Ensure you create this `TextBox` with `Visible` = `False` on a form which is always loaded. You then just need to use this code:

```
BOOL WINAPI SetWindowText(
  _In_      HWND hWnd,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpString
);

HWND m_hWndTextBox

void StartUp(HWND hWndTextBox)
{
    m_hWndTextBox = hWndTextBox;
    // other stuff
}

void Callback(char *cstr) {
    SetWindowText(m_hWndTextBox, cstr);
}
```

And the VB code:

```
' Form "Form1" with text box "Text1".

Private Declare Sub StartUp Lib "library.dll" (ByVal hWndTextBox As Long)

Public Sub MySub
    Call StartUp(Text1.hWnd)
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_Change()
    DoStuffWithDLLUpdateString Text1.Text
End Sub
```

And you don't even have to convert the string to a BSTR - VB does that for you.

Comment: This is great as this is pretty close to what I need.  Unfortunately, I can't quite rely on always being able to set the text to the string I'm using.  Instead, the string gets used in some odd ways based on some complex VB6 business logic.  So I think that means that I need to use the trickier `SendMessage` method that you mentioned.  I've found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176058/en-us) article which describes the process pretty well.  Unfortunately, I've not been able to get it to work (I'm not seeing my custom WindowProc function get called with the WM_COPYDATA parameter).

Comment: Actually, behind the scenes, SetWindowText() actually calls SendMessage() with wMsg = WM_SETTEXT. What odd ways are you talking about? Alternatively, perhaps you could show the code you tried with WM_COPYDATA.

Comment: Sometimes the string goes directly into a field on the UI.  Sometimes it gets manipulated and written to a file.  Other times it just goes into a database field, etc.  So I can't really re-implement all of this business logic in C and sort of need it to be accessible in a function in VB.

Comment: The WM_COPYDATA method may not be working properly because I am sort of cheating by not actually filling out a `COPYDATASTRUCT` and just passing 0 (null) as the last parameter to `SendMessage`.  I'm doing this because I already have the string built and passed into VB.  So now what I'm trying is to just save a reference to the string that gets passed into the callback and then call `SendMessage` using a custom message as registered with `RegisterWindowMessage` and then using the referenced string when my registered window message is invoked.  Seems to be working for now (need to do more tests)